# Refreshing page changes the layout of UI

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am new to web development. I am using asp.net. Below is the CSS I use in a .aspx file. When I open it in my phone the UI looks fine although the #background is a little bit longer than the whole page.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #form1 {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #background {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 180%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    #Image1{
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
```

When I click the button, the UI refreshes to make the #background to be the same size as the whole page but extends the size of #Image1. Why does the refresh of page do this? How to avoid it? Thanks.

```
    <div align="center">
        <asp:Button ID="Reserve" runat="server" Width="800px" Text="Reserve" Font-Size="45px" BackColor="OrangeRed" ForeColor="White" OnClick="Reserve_Click"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you need set button type="button" default it is button submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem is in the back-end code

```
Response.Write("<script>alert(....)").
```

After changing it into

```
Page page=this.Page;
if (!page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(page.GetType(), "alert"))
{
  page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "alert", "<script>alert(....)");
}
```

the css is ok. referred from https://blog.csdn.net/woshixuye/article/details/7217261